# C# to cmd prompt window closes to quick

Tags: c#, cmd

I am new to codeing and trying to write a program in C# that will send basic commands to Cmd prompt i am using a windows form with this program. Below is the code i am using. I am able to get the commands to send but the cmd window closes before i can see any output on some of them.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ping command
        string pcname;
        string strCmdText;
        pcname = Convert.ToString(PC.Text);
        strCmdText = $"/c ping {pcname}";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        //ping pcname

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //trace route command
        string pcname;
        string strCmdText;
        pcname = Convert.ToString(PC.Text);
        strCmdText = $"/c tracert {pcname} ";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        //tracert pcname
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //last reboot command
        string pcname;
        string strCmdText;
        pcname = Convert.ToString(PC.Text);
        //wmic /node:DLAT97025 os get lastbootuptime
        strCmdText = $"/c wmic /node:{pcname} os get lastbootuptime";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //shutdown command
        string pcname;
        string shutdown;
        string strCmdText;
        pcname = Convert.ToString(PC.Text);
        shutdown = Convert.ToString(ReasonForShutdown.Text);
        strCmdText = $"/c shutdown /m \\{pcname} /c {shutdown}";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        //shutdown /m \\pcname /c shutdown

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //restart command
        string pcname;
        string restart;
        string strCmdText;
        pcname = Convert.ToString(PC.Text);
        restart = Convert.ToString(ReasonforRestart.Text);
        strCmdText = $"/c shutdown /r \\{pcname} /c {restart}";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        //shutdown /r \\pcname /c restart

    }
```

Comment: Try using `/k` instead of `/c` as your first argument. Info [here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).

Comment: a quick way of keeping cmd open is doing Console.ReadLine()

Comment: That's happen because /c instructs the console to close immediately. You can use /k but then you need to close the console yoursefl